# energy, gravity and buoyancy working together

Tags: kinematics

What will happen to the objects in this youtube video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5FF6DEaXTw

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far to solve this problem??

Comment: What will happen to the objects is a wrong question. It is important to ask what will happen to the _water_. It is not in equilibrium where it is.

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4918/2451

Comment: @JoeArroyo: Video is really poor method of describing problem like this. There is nothing that would really have to be shown as video. At least please transcribe the text description here. And if you have the original image (clearly you uploaded the video, but I don't know whether you made it too) try to include it.

Comment: Why was that a video?  You could have scanned the problem as a pdf or png and posted it here.  Or you could have rewritten the problem on this forum, showing what you've done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The video shows a supposed [perpetuum mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) of the first kind. That can't exist, because it would violate law of conservation of energy. So there should be something wrong with it.

I've taken a still from the video (the frames of the video are all the same except for rotating colours of the objects):

[image: snapshot from the video]

According to the description, part of the machine is filled with water, part is evacuated and the rest has ambient air. So let's colour which is which. Water (blue) is easy; it's everything below the blue lines. But for vacuum there are two options. The description says the inside has vacuum, so let's first fill all of the inside with vacuum (yellow is ambient air, white is vacuum):

[image: coloured, all evacuated, first problem]

But that makes the water level at the bottom inconsistent. The water level in the middle and outside is at the same level, but inside it is at vacuum pressure and outside at ambient pressure.

[image: coloured, all evacuated, second problem]

The connection to outside is not really needed for the device, so that inconsistency can be fixed, but we still get two different water levels in communicating vessels under same (vacuum) pressure which is not possible in equilibrium. And these two parts need to be connected as the marbles have to pass between them and this second inconsistency can't be fixed.

So let's try to evacuate the top part only:

[image: coloured, only top evacuated]

But that just shifted the problem to the water lock in the centre where we now have communicating vessels with the same level but at different pressures where again the vessels must be communicating as marbles have to pass between them.

So what will happen? In either case the pressures will equalize and the objects will just all fall down and float on the water.